# Is it possible to deceive google sign in from another fake application?

Tags: android, google-signin, sha1, android-security

I am currently implementing a native android application. I planned to use Google sign in for it.

I wonder the logic behind the sign in operations.Does google look only for SHA fingerprint and package name to retrieve a user token from their authorization servers? Since we are manually adding these attributes to the developer console.

Is it possible to resign and repack my current application just by changing source codes just to manipulate or send any data he / she wants ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we only issue tokens containing your app's audience to matching signed apks and https origins registered in your OAuth configuration in the Google developers console.